# Kernel density estimation with censored data

Tags: kernel-smoothing, censoring

I have several univariate data sets that I would like to fit with a Kernel density estimator. However, some of the data sets contain left, interval, and right censored observations. How can I implement KDE in the presence of censored data? Is there an R package to do so?

Comment: Can you provide details on what kind of censoring is happening? If it is just certain value ranges that are removed from the data, then estimating the density on the rest of the range should be possible. For more complicated censoring it might not be possible.

Comment: @A.Donda The data are censored since they are not observed as a point, but as an interval. So, for instance an observation can be $(1,2)$, $(5,\infty)$, ...

Comment: I think in that case you should simply use a histogram, where the histogram bins coincide with your observation intervals.